# ADFS - Event ID error 111

Tags: azure-active-directory, adfs3.0

I have ADFS installed on windows server 2012 R2. The IDP sign in page is working fine but I see below error in event logs from past few days.

```
Event ID : 111
The Federation Service encountered an error while processing the WS-Trust request. 
Request type: http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust/RST/Issue 
Additional Data 
Exception details: 
Microsoft.IdentityServer.RequestFailedException: MSIS7012: An error occurred while processing the request. contact your administrator for details
Parameter name: claimType
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Threading.AsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WSTrust.WSTrustServiceContract.ProcessCoreAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult ar)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WSTrust.WSTrustServiceContract.EndProcessCore(IAsyncResult ar, String requestAction, String responseAction, String trustNamespace)
```

Please help me to understand what causing this error, how can I resolve this ?

Comment: This is fairly hideous to read - can you please edit it to use Markdown formatting?  For instance, if you begin the text "Event ID: 111 ..." with a `>` then it will format as a quote, which is a nice way to format error messages.  Also, what have you tried so far?  Thanks, and good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The custom claim rule you have given might be causing this error. You can verify these specific parameters AttributeStore, ClaimRule, ClaimType. You could follow this guide to get some more details from [here](https://www.pagerduty.com/docs/guides/adfs-sso-guide/)

Comment: We only have office 365 relying party. We did not create any custom claims.